# What is the difference between Javascript and Adobe Javascript?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Noticed when browsing for script files in Photoshop you can select standard Javascript (js) files and Adobe Javascript files (jsx). What's the difference?

Comment: I'ved used Adobe InDesign, which utilizes the same .jsx files. As far as I know, it's standard javascript syntax - running on Adobe's javascript engine with Photoshop/InDesign's SDK so you can reference specific objects related to PS/ID. It should all be built in - assuming your using ExtendScript Tool Kit?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JSGuide.pdf

> Acrobat JavaScript is based on the core of JavaScript version 1.5 of
>   `ISO-16262`, formerly  known as `ECMAScript`. Acrobat JavaScript
>   implements extensions, in the  form of new objects and their
>   accompanying methods and properties, to the JavaScript  programming
>   language. These Acrobat-specific objects enable a developer to
>   manipulate  a PDF file, allowing the PDF file to communicate with a
>   database, modify its appearance,  and so on. Because the
>   Acrobat-specific objects are added on top of core JavaScript, you 
>   still have access to standard classes like Math, String, Date, Array,
>   and RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is the trade name for the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) standard. Vendors are free to make changes to it and support or not support specific features.

For specifics on Adobe JavaScript see: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_javascript_ref.pdf

While Mozilla (Netscape) created JavaScript they made it a standard for anyone to use. In the interest of not re-inventing the wheel vendors incorporate JavaScript into various software products. In Adobe's case this means specific functions for their product that is not needed for browser based implementations.